# TFS 2012 and MS SQL 2008r2

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

When I try to  call TFS 2012 warehouse control web service (WarehouseControlService.asmx) I got following error:

Exception Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (type FileNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseConfigurationService.RebuildOLAPDatabase(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, String olapServerInstanceName, String databaseName, String warehouseServerInstanceName, String warehouseDatabaseName, Int32 translationLCID, Boolean checkAndUpdateJobs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseConfigurationService.RebuildOLAPDatabase(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, String olapServerInstanceName, String databaseName, String warehouseServerInstanceName, String warehouseDatabaseName, Int32 translationLCID)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Management.SnapIn.ApplicationTierNode.RebuildReporting(IntPtr hwnd, IRefreshable panel)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (type FileNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Internal.TfsAssemblyResolver.OnAssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)

It is strange because I have installed ms sql connectivity. Is it issue connected with the fact that I try to use tfs 2012 with ms sql 2012? Please advise how to resolve issue networked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have the SQL Server Analysis Services components installed on the web server.

It's a separate install which you can get from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065). Specifically you want to look for the "Microsoft® Analysis Services OLE DB Provider for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012" [on that page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) (about 1/3 of the way down).

The SQL 2008 R2 version can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978).

Comment: Where can someone find that? Although the answer is marked as correct, I couldn't find SSAS Components in SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise... Can someone pls guide where they exist?

Comment: That's a common mistake.  The SSAS drivers aren't actually installed with the SQL Server drivers.  It's a separate install which you can get from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065.  Specifically you want to look for the "Microsoft® Analysis Services OLE DB Provider for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012" on that page (about 1/3 of the way down).

Comment: But the question was to connect TFS 2012 with SQL Server 2008 R2! Are you sure installing "Microsoft® Analysis Services OLE DB Provider for Microsoft® **SQL Server® 2012**" will solve the issue?

Comment: The newer drivers will work find with the older version.  If you prefer the SQL 2008 R2 drivers they can be found at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978

Comment: Thanks a lot, 1 more question I needed to ask... We need to install "cumulative update package 1 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1" for TFS 2012, we installed this on Database Server, but for Reporting and Analysis we are using a separate server... Do we need to install "cumulative update package 1 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1" on the Reporting/Analysis Server as well?

Comment: Yes you'll want to install it on the other machine as well.

Comment: thanks a lot, much appreciated.. if you get stuck with SharePoint sometime, just lemme know! I help people on SharePoint.stackexchange.com !! Just a payback offer ;)